# AwesomeWM resizing firefox

Tags: firefox, awesome-wm

I am a begginer to AwesomeWM and can't figure out how to resize my firefox window. I can resize terminal windows with Mod4 + H/L but no matter what I do, firefox and my PDF reader are stuck running in full screen mode. When I add terminals to the workspace they will only appear in front of or behind the firefox window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Firefox window is very likely **maximized** or **floating** - you'll notice it by special characters like ↔ or ↕ at the start of the window title in the first case. Try toggling maximization with <kbd>Mod4</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but toggling the maximization did not help so i found out via Documentation that the arrows symbolize horizontal and vertical maximisation so i wrote this keyboard shortcut

```
  awful.key({ modkey, "Shift" }, "m",
function (c)
  c.maximized = false
  c.maximized_vertical=false
  c.maximized_horizontal=false
  c:raise()
end ,
{description = "demaximize", group = "client"})
```

now i can Press

```
mod4-Shift-m
```

and it solved the issue everytime i got this two arrows